# Worker thread that only consumes cpu when there is something in the queue

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

Here is what I am trying to do.

I want to have an object that has a queue and starts a thread. Another thread can push to that queue by doing object.addWork(work);

That will push work into the queue and wake the thread if it it sleeping. The thread then performs the work on each object in the queue until the queue is empty.

Once the queue is empty and no more work is left, that thread sleeps and needs to be awoken by adding to the queue again.

Is there a thread-safe way of making such an object?

Comment: You basically want a `BlockingQueue`; that is what this interface (and implementations) is meant to do.

Comment: what @fge said -- Pick any implementation of BlockingQueue and any implementation of ExecutorService

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically want what `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor` can do

```
class YouNameIt{
    private ExecutorService executor;

    public void start(){
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }

    public void put(Object o){
        executor.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                process(o);
            }
        });
    }

    private void process(Object o) {
        //Put your processing here
    }

    public void stop(){
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```